# c++ incremental type ID across compilation units

Tags: c++, static, initialization, unique, identifier

I need each derived class to have a unique ID, but the ID's need to be incremental.
Here is my current implementation:

```
//component.cpp
class ComponentId
{
public:
    ComponentId();


    static int nextId;
    int id;
};

template<class T>
class Component {
public:
    static const ComponentId componentId;
};

template<class T>
const ComponentId Component<T, chunkSize>::componentId;

///component.cpp
int ComponentId::nextId = 0;

ComponentId::ComponentId() : id(nextId++)
{
}

//IN static library a
struct compA : public Component<compA> {

}

//In static library b
struct compB : public Component<compB> {

}

//in main.cpp
#include <component.h>
#include <compA.h>
#include <compB.h>
std::cout << compA::componentId.id << std::endl;
std::cout << compB::componentId.id << std::endl;
```

This works fine in all my unit tests but doesn't seem to work as intended when using multiple compilation units or across static libraries.
The ID's are reused in different libraries. One library may have id's 0,1,2 and 3, but another library will also have classes with IDs 0 and 1.
My guess is that the nextid field isn't being shared.

I have also tried to use the extern keyword but It seemed to produce the same issue.
I have also tried to make a static getId function in hopes to do initialization on first use, but no such luck.

I really need the IDs to be 'tight', as in 1,2,3,4,5, rather than 67, 80, 123, 1, 4.

Any ideas?

Comment: "but doesn't seem to work" is quite meaningless.  You'll have to explain how it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post.

Comment: Post a [MCVE].  Usually those should be all in one piece, but we can make an exception (snort) in this case.

Comment: Why not just move the `id` into the base class?  Then they all still have an ID they can access and it will be unique and "tight" for all instances.

Comment: @NathanOliver I am not looking to have unique ID's per instance, but a unique ID per Class. (A type ID if you like).
I have also tried without the ComponentId wrapper but it was exactly the same.

Comment: A "type-id" is usually a bad idea. What is the use-case for this "type-id"? What is the actual problem it is supposed to solve?

Comment: @NathanOliver updated the post

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am building an Entity Component System, and need to build bitsets to represent the composition of Entities, and compare them to "Families".

Comment: @felixbridault it's (usually) bad because you don't tie down the numbers at any point - meaning that next time you compile, all your previous ids -> classes are invalidated because the new one you just added took spot 0 (or you removed the one at spot 0; or you just linked in a different way).  If you're aiming to have any backwards compatibility then you'll need to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: @UKMonkey I already have a good mechanism to save and load entities from JSON, using class names. Component ID's are only used internally and do not need to be consistent across runs. Just unique within a run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want a single `int` instance shared across multiple TUs, I think that using an `inline` function that returns a reference to a `static int` should do the trick:

```
// counter.hpp
namespace detail 
{
    inline int& getCounter()
    {
        static int result{0};
        return result;
    }
}

inline int nextId()
{
    return detail::getCounter()++;
}
```

```
// component.cpp
ComponentId::ComponentId() : id(nextId())
{
}
```

---

Nevertheless, this feels brittle and prone to errors, especially if you're aiming to rely on your ID for serialization/deserialization. If you know all the types of your components at compile-time, I suggest using a typelist. E.g.

```
using components = typelist<
    Component0,
    Component1,
    Component2,
    Component3
>;
```

Otherwise, if you only know your components types at run-time, provide some sort of registry that allows users to register/unregister types in a controlled manner.

Comment: Thanks the reference seems to have fixed the issue!
I am not using the id's for serialization, just internal data structures. So it should be ok.